# Excel vba paste on last row of data

Tags: vba, excel

i need some code modifications here, on paste command on vba, but the thing is it will paste on the last row of data

im using this code, and  this work perfectly but when im try to copy another data it replace the current one

```
Range(Range("A2:L2" & lastrow), ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial
```

Comment: You need to watch all the Wise Owl VBA tutorials on Youtube.  Here is the relevant on [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ)

Answer (score 1):

change line as

```
Range(Range("A2:L2" & lastrow), ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).offset(1,0).PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .Insert

```
Sub Macro2()
    Rows("6:6").Copy
    Rows("15:15").Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you modify it to copy the right range and insert at the right range? Perhaps you want xlUp not xlDown?

Your question was pretty unclear about what you want to accomplish, and "its not working" is even more unclear...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your one line of code isn't very much help and the copy line should be there too...

Then :

```
Range(Range("A2:L2" & lastrow), ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).PasteSpecial
```

There is no need to select a range of cells if you copied a range to paste, just the first cell where you want to paste!

So the most important part is the copy!

Your code should look something like this :

```
With ThisWorkBook.Sheets("SheetToCopy")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
    .Range("A2:L" & LastRow).Copy
End With

With ThisWorkBook.Sheets("SheetToPaste")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
    .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial
End With
```